# Display hReviews from other websites such as yelp on your site?

Tags: plugins

Does anyone know of a plugin that reads hReview schema microformat from any website supporting it then can display the reviews on your wordpress site either with a php function or short code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get Yelp reviews via their API without having to scrape their pages (which I'm pretty sure is against their TOS). I'm not aware of a plugin that does it, but they have example php code.

Comment: Yelp is only an example, but I will look at their API. I doubt the PHP examples extracting the reviews directly. With hReview being a standardized format I was hoping to find a plugin that pulled them from any web page which contained them similar to inserting RSS Feeds.